# Что такое асинхронная онлайн галерея?

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый вечер,
Мне задали тестовое задание на собеседовании сделать  асинхронную онлайн галерею, но в интернете не нашел должного объяснения, подскажите в чем её особенности?
Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего они имели ввиду асинхронную загрузку изображений в галерее. Для примера могли бы привести Lazy Load.

## Коротко о Lazy Load:

Изображения — это, как правило, самые тяжелые элементы страницы. Поэтому если на странице изображений много, то не стоит загружать их все сразу. Во-первых, это ускорит загрузку страницы, во-вторых, может существенно снизить нагрузку на сервер, а в-третьих, сэкономит трафик пользователю.

---

## Плюсы Lazy Load:

Отложенная загрузка имеет много преимуществ. Вместо загрузки всего контента она загружает только ту часть, которая видна пользователю в окне браузера. Это может выражаться по-разному, начиная от просто задержки загрузки изображений и заканчивая полномасштабным бесконечным скроллингом контента.

**Высокая скорость загрузки сайта**
Загрузка происходит только тогда, когда это необходимо. Подобная функция помогает значительно увеличить скорость работы сайта в целом. Это отличный способ уменьшить количество посетителей, которые покинули ваш сайт из-за медленной загрузки.

**Интуитивно понятный пользовательский интерфейс** 
Посетителям больше не понадобится нажимать на новую страницу и ждать, пока она загрузится. У них появляется возможность абсолютно спокойно и естественно прокручивать информацию, пока они не найдут то, что искали.

---

## Минусы отложенной загрузки

**Ущерб для SEO**
Да, мы писали, что скорость позитивно повлияет во время сканирования вашего сайта. Однако тут есть и негативное влияние. С учетом того, что некоторый контент просто не появляется до того момента, пока пользователь до него не дойдет, то при сканировании поисковые системы, такие как Google, могут просто его не увидеть. Но такое могло бы случиться и при фиксированном количестве сообщений на сайте. Это просто означает, что поисковая система не может принять во внимание некоторую важную информацию, которая существует ниже в ваших архивах.

**Низкая производительность на старых браузерах**
С учетом того, что контент загружается только тогда, когда пользователи прокручивают сайт до него, могут возникать проблемы с просмотром содержимого из-за производительности, особенно на старых браузерах или при медленном интернете.
Вы, возможно, замечали это во время работы на сайтах с отложенной загрузкой, если вы хотите быстро проскроллить вниз, то вам придется подождать несколько секунд, пока все загрузится.
Кроме того, пользователи не смогут контролировать свои переходы по содержимому или использовать кнопку браузера "Назад", когда будут искать контент, который они недавно просмотрели.

---

## Когда использовать отложенную загрузку

Как вы могли заметить, преимущества и недостатки отложенной загрузки попадают в одни и те же области: поисковая оптимизация и взаимодействие с пользователем.
Чтобы получить максимальную отдачу от отложенной загрузки, нужно использовать ее экономно. Попробуйте использовать ее только на вашей домашней странице или страницах с большим количеством изображений и отключать на страницах, которые размещают ценный SEO контент.
Экспериментируйте и проверяйте ваши данные, используя Google Analytics (для трафика сайта и SEO), Pingdom (для скорости сайта) и просто обращайте внимание на пользовательский фидбэк.

---

**P.S.** В качестве информации были собраны статьи с просторов интернета.

Comment: `пользователи не смогут контролировать свои переходы по содержимому или использовать кнопку браузера "Назад", когда будут искать контент,` - да вроде вполне себе можно это сделать. у ВК с этим проблем нет.....иметь некий инструмент, который показывает на какой ты странице, когда скролишь. или через какой-нибудь `history` pushState  заносить эти данные в историю, вполне себе реально и возможно